# Android Studio > Javascript

Tags: android, android-studio, cross-platform, phonegap

I'm working on a cross platform project, that must work on the Android Studio emulator, and I'm having lots of problems:

1. The project works nice in the browser and the console doesn't show me errors: it nicely calls me the server and there is also a good conversation between them.
2. Then I call the `phonegap build android` command.
3. Opening the created project in Android Studio the result is the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why is that working in one platform and not in the other?

Comment: Does any other apps on the emulator (chrome for example) have an internet access?

Comment: @Taier all of them...

Comment: check your local Urls in your config.xml file. it is not correct hence corodva is not able to locate resources.

Comment: @Ashwani his is my config.xml file, and there's only an URL that starts the application:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>GeoPost</name>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~7.0.0" />
</widget>`

Comment: your config seems to be fine...i wanted to look for access origin..you have allowed all...then problem could be either file name mismatch or missing extension maybe.

Comment: @Ashwani but I didn't touch any file after the phonegap command...

Comment: I mean to say..is your file name Login only check for exact match of path.

Comment: @Ashwani I'm not sure I understand. The file name is index.html (with my form inside), [...]/login is the file in the server, I'm not managing it!